# The incoming request has too many parameters

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, orm

I have the following exception `SQLServerException: The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.` while executing  `SELECT` query via Hibernate.
Here is my query [image]

Does anybody know any solutions for this in Hibernate?
Will be very grateful for any help, thank you!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Split the query into multiple queries if you actually need to retrieve this many rows at once.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for this issue would be to get data in chunks.

```
List<List<Long>> partitions = new ArrayList<List<Long>>();
List<Long> bucket = new ArrayList<>();
int count = 0;
for(Long id : ids){
count++;
if(count>1000){
count = 1;
partitions.add(bucket);
bucket = new ArrayList<>();
}
partitions.add(bucket);
}
List<PreStagePaymentData> data= new ArrayList<>();
List<PreStagePaymentData> temp;
for(List<Long> partition : partitions){
temp = findPreStageDataByPaymentIds(partition);
data.addAll(temp);
}
```