# The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters in Grails

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, grails

I use MSSQL witch has constaints. And I get error:

Class
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException
Message
The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.

In this plase:

```
final Set<User> unavailableUsers = ctx.delegationService.getUnavailableUserVariants()
    
if (unavailableUsers) {
    inList 'key', unavailableUsers*.key
}
```

unavailableUsers has many Users about 2500.

How to solve this problem?

I try to do chunks of array

```
final Set<User> unavailableUsers = ctx.delegationService.getUnavailableUserVariants()

List<Set<User>> output = new ArrayList<>()
Set<User> currSet = null
for (CatalogUser value : unavailableUsers) {
    if (currSet == null || currSet.size() == 1000)
        output.add(currSet = new HashSet<User>());
    currSet.add(value);
}

output.each {it ->
    if (it) {
        inList 'key', it*.key
    }
}
```

But it doesn't help

Comment: Break it down into chunks of 500 or so?

Comment: And how to do it?

Comment: final Set<CatalogUser> unavailableUsers = ctx.delegationService.getUnavailableUserVariants()

    List<Set<CatalogUser>> output = new ArrayList<>()
    Set<CatalogUser> currSet = null
    for (CatalogUser value : unavailableUsers) {
        if (currSet == null || currSet.size() == 1000)
            output.add(currSet = new HashSet<CatalogUser>());
        currSet.add(value);
    }

    output.each {it ->
        if (it) {
            inList 'key', it*.key
        }
    }

Comment: I try to do it, but it doesn't help

Comment: If you're using JDBC >= 6 you can use [table-valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters), by far the most efficient way to pass a set to SQL Server. Failing that (or if your Hibernate thing can't support it) you can build a single CSV and parse it on the other side using `STRING_SPLIT()`. But that won't work well for 2500 values either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64104377/6572971 have a look at it might help you.

Comment: "Break it down into chunks of 500 or so?" - @AndrewCorrigan I am not sure that will help. From the code in the question, I _think_ the issue is with the criteria, not the results.